# REST side not knowing if SignalR is attempting to connect for the first time or reconnect

Tags: get, signalr, middleware, reconnect

```
this.hubConn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("https://server/hubEndPoint}", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
```

When SignalR attempts to start the connection with the server using `HttpTransportType.WebSockets`, it makes a "GET" call to the server to start it. My middleware intercepts the GET call and I see all the variables of the context (request, headers etc.). However on the reconnect (triggered by `withAutomaticReconnect()`) SignalR makes another GET call to reconnect to the same URL it was initially built with. So my middleware on the server side intercepts it again. And that is all fine, the issue is that I see NOTHING that is telling me that this second request is made because of reconnection.